# nginx variable for path of config file

Tags: nginx, config

Is there a way to specify, for example, that the `root` should be relative to the directory where the config file is living? Something like

```
root $conf_path/www
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, I don't believe this is possible.  But, you might be able to hack something together based on [this article](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2583637).

Quoting relevant parts:

> 2ed version is here:
>   [How to reference OS Environment Variables in nginx.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439515)
>
> Posted at Nginx Forum:
>   http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,215269,215278#msg-215278

and further

> You can read system environment variables with ngx_lua enabled in your
>   nginx build: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule

```
env PATH;
http {
    ...
    server {
        location /path {
            set_by_lua $path 'return os.getenv("PATH")';
            ...
        }
    }
```

> BTW, to use the set_by_lua directive, you also need to enable the
>   ngx_devel_kit module here: https://github.com/simpl/ngx_devel_kit
>   (it'll be easier if you use the ngx_openresty bundle).

Answer (score 9):

You can actually do that using the `-p` option.

If you have your config file in the same directory as your app you can run:

```
/your/folder $ sudo nginx -c `pwd`/nginx.conf -p "`pwd`"
```

from your app folder.
Your `nginx.conf` file changes from:

```
http {
    include mime.types;
    root /your/folder;
    server {
        listen 8000;
    }
}
```

to

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    root .;
    server {
        listen 8000;
    }
}
```

just make sure that you check relative links that pointed to `/etc/nginx/`