# configuring nginx to serve static files from a custom directory

Tags: nginx

So I want to serve static files from a specific folder on a specific port with Nginx.

```
$ nginx -c `pwd`/nginx.conf
```

my local  `nginx.conf` goes like:

```
http {
    server {
        root .;
        listen 8080;
    }
}
```

but i'm getting this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration
```

I can see the events section in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` but I don't want to have to duplicate all the configuration. There has to be a way to use the default settings and just different port number for a specific folder.

What am I missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify minimal events block:

```
events {
    worker_connections        1024;
}
```

Root needs to be declared with absolute path on the filesystem.

Comment: Actually root support relative path: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865196/nginx-variable-for-path-of-config-file/25486871#25486871)